# Blender will not allow union or differance with 4 joined spheres to a cuber

Tags: modifiers

I am making a mold have actually created the first of mold with an imported .stl and split the mold (wonderful).  Now I need mold keys so both half's fit exactly.  I place for larger sphere at each corner, and 4 smaller sphere inside the larger sphere.  I joined the larger spheres, did a join for the smaller spheres.  Now I am using a modifier to union the smaller sphere to one side of my mold, and a modifier to difference the other side of the mold.  I tested using just one sphere it works.  When I put a small sphere inside a bigger sphere Blender will not do the modifications.  I found where sometimes Blender will have issue with this situation.  Any work around so I can get my mold keys made?   If you not guessed I am new to Blender, but have programming background.  Need this mold to work, please help

Comment: Without any images this really hard to follow. General rule is avoid booleans except for very specific cases, they are unrealiable, will produce bad topology, and issues like the ones you are experiencing

Comment: Boolean - difference (just one) worked well with difference to make the initial mold .  So is Blender not suited for making a mold?

Comment: What software which is stand a lone on computer, good for making a mold design in?   I do not have good internet access live in the country.  Any other software I can use?   Thanks for the help

Comment: Generally speaking if you want to use boolean based workflows you should probably be looking into 3D CAD applications based on either ACIS solid modeling or NURBS, bad news is there aren't many decent free alternatives. See [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org) or [MoI](http://moi3d.com) for a cheap alternative

Comment: I used booleans on the object cylinder.  I believe I need a higher end computer and graphics card to get sphere booleans to work.  I found 3 YouTube videos using sphere booleans and they worked for them.  Thanks for the help.  I am getting a high end computer with graphics card.

Comment: Forgot to mention the cylinder worked great with booleans.